# Convert "audio" from website to "text" in python

Tags: web, audio

Convert "audio" from website to "text" in python

New to Gptchat and AI related things.

Today looked up how to convert audio from a website or app to text, for transcription ease, and I saw this page [Convert sound from website to text in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787629/convert-sound-from-website-to-text-in-python..). and wanted to know how could I do this for any website with audio (including a Spotify podcast)?
I tried using the above coding and replaced the http with the Spotify link (copied from the share area) and python just returned a reply saying "did you mean r" and I dont know what to do next.
This would greatly help me in saving parts of a podcast to my notes or whatever, if it could work. Any advice is appreciated. Thx